# Java - Sonar - Arrays should not be copied using loops

Tags: java, arrays, sonarqube

My java code:

```
public class TestArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String[] cols = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>(4);

        // for (int i = 1; i < cols.length - 1; i++) {
        // columns.add(cols[i]);
        // }
        System.arraycopy(cols, 0, columns, 0, cols.length - 1);

        for (String c : columns) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

    }

}
```

Sonar say: **Arrays should not be copied using loops**

Using a loop to copy an array or a subset of an array is simply wasted code when there are built-in functions to do it for you. Instead, use Arrays.copyOf to copy an entire array into another array, use System.arraycopy to copy only a subset of an array into another array, and use Arrays.asList to feed the constructor of a new list with an array.

Note that Arrays.asList simply puts a Collections wrapper around the original array, so further steps are required if a non-fixed-size List is desired.

so, I try this:

```
System.arraycopy(cols, 1, columns, 0, cols.length -1);
```

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.company.TestArray.main(TestArray.java:16)
```

I think my problem come from array is not list

Comment: "I have an error." what is the error? Is `cols` a primitive array?

Comment: I think the problem is that `columns` is some collection, as I can see `columns.add(...)` in OP's code.

Comment: @AndyTurner, `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`

Comment: As @JaroslawPawlak says: `columns` is not an array, so you can't store array elements in it like that.

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes but why Sonar say an error on my `for` loop?

Comment: Because your for loop explicitly iterates an array, and it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `System.arraycopy` to store data in something that's not an array. As it states [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-):

> ... if any of the following is true, an `ArrayStoreException` is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>
> - The `src` argument refers to an object that is not an array.
> - The `dest` argument refers to an object that is not an array.
> - ...

If `cols` is a reference-typed array, just use `Arrays.asList` and `subList`:

```
columns.addAll(Arrays.asList(cols).subList(1, cols.length - 1));
```

Comment: I would have also added to your answer this part of the java doc of the `arraycopy` method: "if any of the following is true, an ArrayStoreException is thrown and the destination is not modified: (...) The dest argument refers to an object that is not an array."

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
columns = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(col, 1, col.length));
```

or this

```
columns.addAll(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(col, 1, col.length )));
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?
@AndreasRadauer Why copying the array before feeding it to the `asList(...)`?